# MX Record For Hosted Domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, mx-record

I have an exchange server with multiple domains hosted on it. Lets say these are the domains.

company1.com (main), company2.com, company3.com

The server uses email.company1.com for its name on the send and receive connectors and also has an ssl certificate for the name email.company1.com.

For company1.com there is an A record with email pointing the servers IP address. Also there is an MX record pointing to this A record.

For company2.com and company3.com there is an MX record pointing to email.company1.com.

I'm having some issues with bounced emails from company2.com and company3.com to certain domains. Here is the message I those users get back.

"Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record"

This suggests that I need an A record for my MX record in company2.com and company3.com. This isn't possible as an A record does not work that way. How do I get this setup correctly?

It seems I may need a reverse entry for email.company1.com for company2.com and company3.com. Does this sound right, do I do this in the dns of company2 and company3?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example based on your example :

```
mail.com.        IN A            10.10.10.10
company1.com.             IN MX 10        mail.com.
company2.com.             IN MX 10        mail.com.
company3.com.             IN MX 10        mail.com.
```